How to Reposition Child Nodes Dynamically in Balkan Chart API?
I'm currently working with the Balkan Chart API to create an organizational chart, and I need to dynamically reposition child nodes when a parent node is expanded. My goal is to keep the heights consistent across the chart when expanding or collapsing nodes.
Problem Description:
I want to implement a feature where all level 2 nodes remain visible, and when a level 2 node is expanded, its child nodes should adjust their positions without altering the overall chart height. I've attempted to use methods like set, but I keep running into issues where child nodes are not found or the chart does not render correctly after trying to reposition them.
Current Approach:
I have the following function that is supposed to move child nodes up or down based on their parent node's position:
function moveChildNodes(chart, parentNode) {
    console.log("Moving child nodes for parent:", parentNode);
    
    var childrenIds = parentNode.childrenIds;

    if (!Array.isArray(childrenIds) || childrenIds.length === 0) {
        console.log("No child nodes found for parent node with ID:", parentNode.id);
        return; // Exit if no children
    }

    var parentNodeElement = chart.getNodeElement(parentNode.id);
    if (!parentNodeElement) {
        console.error("Parent node element not found for ID:", parentNode.id);
        return; // Skip if parent is not found
    }

    var baseY = parentNodeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var nodeHeight = parentNodeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    childrenIds.forEach(function (childId, index) {
        console.log("Looking for child node ID:", childId);
        
        var childNodeElement = chart.getNodeElement(childId);
        if (!childNodeElement) {
            console.error("Child node element not found for ID:", childId);
            return; // Skip if child is not found
        }

        var newY = baseY + (nodeHeight * (index + 1)); // Calculate new Y position

        // Attempt to set the new position using the chart API
        chart.set(childId, { y: newY });
    });

    chart.draw(); // Redraw the chart to apply changes
}

Issues Encountered:
Child Node Not Found: I sometimes receive errors indicating that the child node elements are not found.
Move Function Not Available: I cannot find a move method to reposition nodes dynamically.
Repositioning Logic: The logic to calculate new positions doesn't seem to maintain a consistent height across the chart.
Request for Help:
What is the correct method to reposition child nodes in the Balkan Chart API?
Are there specific examples or documentation that could help me understand how to implement this feature effectively?
How can I ensure that the chart maintains consistent heights when expanding or collapsing nodes?

This is not supported in the current version.

I work in the company. The customer wants the children to fit the chart height when expand 2 and 6 in the below example: https://code.balkan.app/first-example#JS It is possible only for 2. For 6 there is possibility to try some custom solution, but it will not work with all cases.

Hi @DarkBee. I work in the company. The customer wants the children to fit the chart height when expand 2 and 6 in the below example:
https://code.balkan.app/first-example#JS
It is possible only for 2.
For 6 there is possibility to try some custom solution, but it will not work with all cases.

it's better when you disclose this information in your answer
